# access update table on button click using two fields for identification

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So I have a button in an MS access 2010 form that updates a table when clicked. my VBA looks like this:

```
currentdb().execute ("update mytable set mytable.field="text" 
where name=" & name)
```

This works, but the problem is my name field is one to many. I need it to be one to one. In order to do this, I have to add a second column, lastname. If I could make it lastname + name, then it would be unique and one to one. I tried to make the code someone like:

```
currentdb().execute ("update mytable set mytable.field="text" 
where name=" & name and "where lastname =" & lastname
```

Obviously this doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `AND` in your `WHERE` criteria:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourfield = somevalue
WHERE name = 'John'
    AND lastname = 'Doe'
```

Comment: the button on the form has to match the name in the form to the name is the table, note the [name= & name] portion. Also, I tried adding an 'and' statement as you can see in my question on the second line of code I typed.

Comment: @joeumlo -- you used the `where` keyword twice.  The syntax should be `where field = val and field2 = val2...`.  Not really understanding the rest of your comment.

Comment: your answer does not include the join from my form to my table. The button that is running this update query sits on a form. This vba runs to update a table in the same DB. So the answer would be something like where name= & name and lastname= & lastname. make sense?